# I rewrote my program and need some suggestions for my git repo

Tags: git

My program has gone through a rewrite. I have done all the work in a separate git repo but I want to it all back to the original.

Is there a good way to do this so that it is obvious that this a new rewrite? Something like rename master and start a new master branch?

I don't really want the master logs to include the original and rewrite commits.

**Edit/Solution:**

I ended up moving the master branch to _master and created a new bare master. This was hard because gitlab was being obstructive. I had to make another branch the master before I could rename it.

I pushed the new repository to the master branch of this repo.

I now have a branch that has two distinct branches with everything working and it displays nicely in the network graph in gitlab. It is clear that master is not a continuation of the old code and is a rewrite.

Comment: do you mean you want to keep both the versions in same repository?

Comment: Yes. Though the old version will no longer be maintained.

Comment: Why don't you just release a new version and keep the both versions in the same repository like everybody is managing versions?

Comment: I guess that is what I want to do and I was hoping to get some help but instead got a down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to merge these two repository.
here is a answer about how to do this:

[How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

- although I will still ask if I have rewritten everything and is better version why I need to worry about the old version.

Comment: We use gitlab to manage our repository, documentation and issues. The issues and doco tie back to specific code in the repository and this is useful information.

Comment: This link really helped but wasn't directly what I ended up doing. I've updated the question. Thanks for the help Shunya

Answer (score 0):

Even if the *code* is fresh, it is still worth keeping the history in the *repo*. What I would do in this case is first add the.

What I would do is: first add a commit in the old version of the code that renames it such that it won't conflict with any of the files in the new version; then rebase the new version on top of that commit, then delete the old version of the code.

The man page for `git rebase` is likely to give you a headache at first, but it is the most useful git command ever.